# Is it possible to double the width of play buttons in NCH Videopad Professional?

Tags: button, screen

Is it possible to double the width of play buttons in NCH Videopad Professional?

on below screenshot I mean buttons in the white ellipse

button widths with red arrows (all buttons in the line, not just the actually arrowed ones)

would be double the width

I often mishitting [next frame button] for [to the very end button]

that's what I'm trying to avoid

Please help me with this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0VdL.jpg)

I'm not in the IT sector, what could I do?